# Cannot debug System.Web.MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug into `System.Web.MVC` but it says that the source is not found.

Here's my config.

[image]

With those symbols in this order like mentioned [here](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio)

- http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
- http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public
- http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/MyGet
- http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

In the module window, it says that `System.Web.MVC` is loaded but when I press `F11` on `return View()`, it asked me for the path of `Controller.cs`

I tried to rename the folder for `System.Web.MVC` in the `GAC` without any success.

Is it important where the symbols are stored? It's on a my `C:` drive.

The error
[image]

The symbol property
[image]

Comment: Are you in Debug mode?

Comment: Yes and when I build it takes a lot of time because it's downloading all the symbols

Answer (score -1):

Can you please verify that you have pdb file at following location.

c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\System.Web.MVC.pdb

If yes please check the permission for this file. If appropriate permission not there then you have to give it explicitly.

**Update**
Can you please let me know why you need to debug the framework dll. If you have any question on using MVC then please ask relevant question.

If you really need to modify the MVC component for your custom need. Then MVC is an open source. Please download the source and debug/modify it.